# NServiceBus Reverts back to XmlSerilizer for no reason

Tags: nservicebus

I am having issues with NSB reverting to the Xml Serializer for no apparent reason which obvisouly causes an error when trying to deserialize the message. Below is an excerpt from the log, as you can see some come through from the same source as Json and then all of a sudden XML!

2018-06-05 08:51:36.924 INFO  Stockly.Services.Messaging.Common.Extensions.MessageBodyWriter Serialized Message Body:
2018-06-05 08:51:37.026 INFO  Stockly.Services.Messaging.Common.Extensions.MessageBodyWriter ﻿{"Exchange":"Binance","Symbol":"SYSBTC","MinutesPerCandle":15}
2018-06-05 08:51:38.505 INFO  Stockly.Services.QuoteService.QuoteHandler Received quote request for SYSBTC and retrived 1000 candles
2018-06-05 08:51:38.725 INFO  Stockly.Services.Messaging.Common.Extensions.MessageBodyWriter Serialized Message Body:
2018-06-05 08:51:38.728 INFO  Stockly.Services.Messaging.Common.Extensions.MessageBodyWriter ﻿{"Exchange":"Binance","Symbol":"DASHBTC","MinutesPerCandle":15}
2018-06-05 08:51:39.194 INFO  Stockly.Services.QuoteService.QuoteHandler Received quote request for DASHBTC and retrived 1000 candles
2018-06-05 08:51:39.228 INFO  Stockly.Services.Messaging.Common.Extensions.MessageBodyWriter Serialized Message Body:
2018-06-05 08:51:39.230 INFO  Stockly.Services.Messaging.Common.Extensions.MessageBodyWriter ﻿{"Exchange":"Binance","Symbol":"ENJBTC","MinutesPerCandle":15}
2018-06-05 08:51:39.715 INFO  Stockly.Services.QuoteService.QuoteHandler Received quote request for ENJBTC and retrived 1000 candles
2018-06-05 08:51:39.774 INFO  Stockly.Services.Messaging.Common.Extensions.MessageBodyWriter Serialized Message Body:
2018-06-05 08:51:39.777 INFO  Stockly.Services.Messaging.Common.Extensions.MessageBodyWriter BinanceRPXBTC15
2018-06-05 08:51:39.824 ERROR NServiceBus.RecoverabilityExecutor Moving message 'f095da8a-e830-4873-8fa0-a8f200719739' to the error queue 'error' because processing failed due to an exception:
NServiceBus.MessageDeserializationException: An error occurred while attempting to extract logical messages from incoming physical message f095da8a-e830-4873-8fa0-a8f200719739 ---> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue()

Here is the configuration.

```
public static EndpointConfiguration ConfigureSerialization(this EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration)
        {
            var serialization = endpointConfiguration.UseSerialization<NewtonsoftSerializer>();
            serialization.ContentTypeKey("NewtonsoftJson");
            var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto,
                Converters =
                    {
                        new IsoDateTimeConverter
                        {
                            DateTimeStyles = DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind
                        }
                    }
            };

            serialization.Settings(settings);
            endpointConfiguration.RegisterMessageMutator(new MessageBodyWriter());

            var externalNewtonsoftJson = endpointConfiguration.AddDeserializer<NewtonsoftSerializer>();
            externalNewtonsoftJson.ContentTypeKey("NewtonsoftJson");

            return endpointConfiguration;
        }
```

Any idea why this might be happening and how I can stop this from occurring?

P.S. at the moment I am using the LearningTransport.

Comment: Not sure why you are overriding the content type key.

Is your sending endpoint correctly configured?

What is also strange if that you register a serializer twice, with the same content type key but different settings.

Comment: Cross posted here https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/issues/5181

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be some left over messages from previous test runs that still used xml as the serialization format. Clearing the input queue solved the issue.

More details: https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/issues/5181#issuecomment-396141572